# insert date to db with three fields PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql

i need to insert date with three textboxes. textbox for year should have a length of four numbers, two length for month and two for day. and additionally user should not can insert words.

```
<label for="textfield"></label>
<label for="t1">year</label>
<input type="text" name="t1" id="textfield" width="50" />
<label for="t2">month</label>
<input type="text" name="t2" id="textfield" width="30" />
<label for="t3">day</label>
<input type="text" name="t3" id="textfield" width="30" />
```

[image]

> i have a table in my db with date format. how insert these fields to date field of my table?

Comment: Don't use `id="textfield"`. ID's should be unique.  Either use a `class="textfield"` or increment each id like `id="textfield1" id="textfield2" ect`

Comment: Why let them type in the year, month, day? Why not selects, or a date picker?

Comment: @chris85 good idea, so i need to use three for?

Comment: You could use three or you could use an already built datepicker which would format the date string for you. http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML or https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ or search on google `jquery datepicker`. You also should validate the data server side as well though to make sure it was manipulated (or if JS was disabled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if date exists. Then you can make your query. Also try to use prepare statements to avoid SQL Injection.

```
$date = $_GET['t1'].'-'.$_GET['t2'].'-'.$_GET['t3'];
if (is_int($_GET['t1']) && is_int($_GET['t2']) && is_int($_GET['t3']) &&  checkdate($_GET['t2'], $_GET['t3'], $_GET['t1'])) {

    //You can use also: 
    //filter_var($_GET['t1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) && filter_var($_GET['t2'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) && filter_var($_GET['t3'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)

    //Validate your inputs and use prepare statements, this is only for demonstrating purposes
    $sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (date_field) VALUES('$date')";
    //Execute your sql query here
} else {
    echo 'Date does not exist.';
}
```

Using PDO:

```
try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$database, $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    if (is_int($_GET['t1']) && is_int($_GET['t2']) && is_int($_GET['t3']) && checkdate($_GET['t2'], $_GET['t3'], $_GET['t1'])) {

        //You can use also: 
        //filter_var($_GET['t1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) && filter_var($_GET['t2'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) && filter_var($_GET['t3'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)

        $date = $_GET['t1'].''.$_GET['t2'].''.$_GET['t3'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (date_field) VALUES(:date_field)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':date_field'=>$date));

    } else {
        echo 'Date does not exist.';
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict what is input into the form in the first place you can use the html5 supported input type "number" along with the maxlength property.

```
<input type="number"maxlength="4">
```

But I would do away with the three fields and just use one. And use a field mask to restrict what can be put in. Like this plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ or http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/